# The property 'unobtrusive' does not exist on value of type 'Validator'

Tags: jquery, validation, typescript

I get an ugly error using typescript with jQuery validation.
The property 'unobtrusive' does not exist on value of type 'Validator'
I have the jQuery typescript d.ts file and the jQuery validation d.ts file. is there another d.ts file I need?

thanks

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Please be more mindful when tagging.  The jQuery Validation Engine is a totally different plugin.

Answer (score 2):

The jQuery validation library doesn't have a property named `unobtrusive`. I couldn't find one in the documentation for it and there isn't one in the definition file:

https://github.com/borisyankov/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/jquery.validation/jquery.validation.d.ts

Therefore I think you are using some other plugin or library... so you will either need to [find a type definition for it or write one](https://www.stevefenton.co.uk/Content/Blog/Date/201301/Blog/Complex-TypeScript-Definitions-Made-Easy/).

For example, if you use it like this:

```
$.unobtrusive('...').text('Hello World);
```

You could extend the jQuery interface like so:

```
interface JQueryStatic {
    unobtrusive(ar: string): JQuery;
}
```

Comment: I am using the jquery validation that comes with a mvc5 project, and $.validator.unobtrusive.parse(f) works.

Comment: sorry didn't finish my comment, the work around I came up with was (<any>$.validator).unobtrusive.parse(f), tnanks

Answer (score 1):

you need a .d.ts for jquery-validation-unobtrusive, perhaps [this](https://github.com/retyped/jquery-validation-unobtrusive-tsd-ambient) or [this](https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/36d40a63a05b5cb3413737fbdf7c9a2a26f211fd/jquery-validation-unobtrusive/jquery-validation-unobtrusive.d.ts)